# go-get cannot download from github

Tags: github, go-get

I installed a go and I think it is correct.

```
$go version
go version go1.15.2 darwin/amd64

$GO111MODULE=on go get -d github.com/XXX@v0.XXX
```

when I downloaded a gihub repo using go, it showed error:

```
go: downloading github.com/XXX/XXX v0.XXX
go get github.com/XXX/XXX@v0.XXX: github.com/XXX/XXX@v0.XXX: verifying module: github.com/XXX/XXX@v0.XXX: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/XXX/XXX@v0.XXX: 410 Gone
server response: not found: github.com/XXX/XXX@v0.XXX: invalid version: unknown revision v0.XXX
```

I do not know much about go language. why the go get does not work? is it because I did not install go correctly or go version is too new?